# Прошу дать рекомендации по поводу кода на Python

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Я буквально вчера начал изучение Python по книге "A byte of python" и сегодня её закончил. Я выполнил заключительную задачу в книге (Адресный справочник), программа работает как нужно, однако, мой вопрос касается качества кода. По итогу я посмотрел подсказку в книге по этой задаче и понял, что делал совсем не так, как там советуется. Мне интересно знать, насколько эффективен мой код (для меня он походит на какое то чудовище), а так же насколько он хорошо оформлен. Буду рад советам и рекомендациям

Код я загрузил на гитхаб, посмотреть его можно здесь: https://github.com/GRUB666/Sundry/blob/master/ContactData.py

Вот чисто код (но отображается он криво):

```
import os
import pickle

#Name of save file
file_way = 'Contacts.dat'
List = []

class Date():
    '''Save info about date

    Atributes: __year, __month, __day
    Functions: getters and setters, printDate() - format: [year.month.day]'''

    def __init__(self, year = 1991, month = 1, day = 1):
        self.__year = year
        self.__month = month
        self.__day = day

    #Getters
    def getYear(self): return self.__year

    def getMonth(self): return self.__month

    def getDay(self): return self.__day

    #Setters
    def setYear(self, year): self.__year = year

    def setMonth(self, month): self.__month = month

    def setDay(self, day): self.__day = day


    def printDate(self):
        print("{}.{}.{}".format(self.__year, self.__month, self.__day))

class ContactData():
    '''Info about person in contacts

    Atributes: __name, __birthday, __number, __adress
    Functions: getters and setters, printInfo()'''
    def __init__(self, name = '', birthday = Date(), number = '', adress = ''):
        self.__name = name
        self.__birthday = birthday
        self.__number = number
        self.__adress = adress

    #Getters
    def getName(self): return self.__name

    def getBirthday(self): return self.__birthday

    def getNumber(self): return self.__number

    def getAdress(self): return self.__adress

    #Setters
    def setName(self, name): self.__name = name

    def setBirthday(self, birthday): self.__birthday = birthday

    def setNumber(self, number): self.__number = number

    def setAdress(self, adress): self.__adress = adress


    def printInfo(self):
        print("Имя: ", self.__name)
        print("День рождения: ", end = ''); self.__birthday.printDate()
        print("Номер телефона: ", self.__number)
        print("Адрес: ", self.__adress)


def initializateList():
    '''Load list of contacts from memory

    (Called only once during program execution)'''
    global List

    try:
        f = open(file_way, 'rb')
        List = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        List = []

def saveContacts():
    '''Save List of contacts in file'''
    global List
    global file_way
    f = open(file_way, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(List, f)
    f.close()



def showAllContacts():
    '''Outputs names of all contacts'''
    global List

    if len(List) > 0:
        print("Всего контактов: ", len(List), "\n\n")
        for i in range(len(List)):
            print("{} - {}".format(i + 1, List[i].getName()))
    else:
        print("Контактов нет")

    print("\n\n")

def createNewContact():
    global List
    '''Create object ContactData

    return new List of contacts'''
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    NewContact = ContactData()

    print("Заполните информацию о новом контакте (Неизвестную информацию можно не заполнять, вы сможете добавить её потом)")

    NewContact.setName(input("Введите имя для нового контакта: "))
    NewContact.setBirthday(Date(input("Введите год рождения: "), input("Введите номер месяца рождения: "), input("Введите день рождения: ")))
    NewContact.setNumber(input("Введите номер телефона: "))
    NewContact.setAdress(input("Введите адрес: "))

    List.append(NewContact)

    saveContacts()

def deleteContact():
    '''Delete contact from List

    return new List of contacts'''
    global List

    while True:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        showAllContacts()

        ch = int(input("Введите индекс элемента, который вы хотите удалить (для выхода введите -1): "))

        if ch > 0 and ch < len(List) + 1:
            del List[ch - 1]
            break
        elif ch >= len(List) + 1:
            print("Этого индекса нет в списке!")
            input("Введите любой символ для продолжения: ")
        else:
            break

    saveContacts()

def showAdditionalInfo():
    '''Show full info about contact'''

    global List

    while True:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        showAllContacts()

        ch = int(input("Введите индекс элемента, о котором вы хотите узнать информацию (для выхода введите -1): "))
        if ch > 0 and ch < len(List) + 1:
            print("\nДополнительная информация о: " + List[ch - 1].getName() + ": ")
            List[ch - 1].printInfo()
            break
        elif ch >= len(List) + 1:
            print("Этого индекса нет в списке!")
            input("Введите любой символ для продолжения: ")
        else:
            break

def changeContact():
    '''Change contact

    return new contact List'''

    global List

    while True:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        showAllContacts()

        ch = int(input("Введите индекс элемента, информацию о котором вы хотите изменить (для выхода введите -1): "))

        if ch > 0 and ch < len(List) + 1:
            while True:
                ind = input("Выберите столбец, который вы хотите изменить:\n1 - Имя\n2 - День рождения\n3 - Номер телефона\n4 - Адрес\n5 - Выход")
                if ind == '1':
                    List[ch - 1].setName(input("Введите новое имя: "))
                elif ind == '2':
                    List[ch - 1].setBirthday(Date(input("Введите новый год рождения: "), input("Введите новый номер месяца рождения: "), input("Введите новый день рождения: ")))
                elif ind == '3':
                    List[ch - 1].setNumber(input("Введите новый номер телефона: "))
                elif ind == '4':
                    List[ch - 1].setNumber(input("Введите новый адрес: "))
                else:
                    break
            break
        elif ch >= len(List) + 1:
            print("Этого индекса нет в списке!")
            input("Введите любой символ для продолжения: ")
        else:
            break

    saveContacts()



#Load Data
initializateList()

#MainLoop
while True:
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    showAllContacts()
    ch = input("Что вы хотели бы сделать?\n\n1 - Создать новую запись\n2 - Удалить существующую\n3 - Узнать подробнее о какой либо записи\n4 - Изменить запись\n\n")

    if ch == '1':
        createNewContact()
    elif ch == '2':
        deleteContact()
    elif ch == '3':
        showAdditionalInfo()
        input("\nВведите любой символ для продолжения: ")
    elif ch == '4':
        changeContact()

    else:
        print("Этого индекса нет в списке!")
        input("Введите любой символ для продолжения: ")
```

P.S. Мне как С++ программисту сложно привыкнуть к некоторым различиям, и у меня неприятное ощущение, будто бы я невольно пытаюсь перенести С++ в Питон

Comment: Лучше вставить код в текст вопроса.

Comment: Чтобы отображалось не криво над редактором есть специальная волшебная кнопка.

Comment: Не по pep8: тело функций на одной строке с определением функции, именование функций. По стилю - глобальные переменные строго не рекомендуются к использованию на любом языке высокого уровня (тем более, что если вы используете ООП, то `global` вам не нужно). Вместо методов-геттеров/сеттеров (в стиле Java) можно использовать свойства (@property) с сеттерами. Плюс, если вы никак не ограничиваете что в поля пишется, можно использовать просто публичные поля.

Comment: Оказывается, я неправильно пользовался кнопкой вставки кода, теперь разобрался

Comment: Спасибо, честно говоря, по книге не было особо понятно, что глобальных переменных стоит избегать. Что же касается оформления методов (тело и реализация в одной строке), то, как я понимаю, если использовать @property, отпадает и нужда в такой записи, но я пока про это ничего не знал, спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не принимай на свой счет, но мне физически больно читать этот код. :) Для начала воспользуйся `pylint`. Он выдаст тебе кучу предупреждений, исправь их, чтоб глаза не вытекали.

Проблема в том, что непонятно, где "учебный эксперимент", а где избыточный код.

**UPD**: Раз уж кто-то считает это полезным.

Самая принципиальная проблема, которой я тоже страдал, пока не **начал читать чужой код** - реализация классов "с нуля".

1. Когда у тебя появилась мысль создать новый класс, следующей мыслью должна быть: "Хммм... А на что это похоже? Может это словарь? Список? Строка? Генератор? Просто такой... Специфичный...". И ты наследуешься от соответствующего встроенного класса. Для этого тебе надо знать: [Как вообще работают классы](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), [Популярные классы для наследования](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html), [Как класс с данными организовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).
2. Не пиши уникальные методы для стандартных задач. Метод: `print_me` - ужасная идея. Почему ты и твои коллеги должны помнить, что все классы - "нормальные", а твой - "уникален"? Если твой класс печатается иначе, перегрузи стандартный метод печати `__str__` и забудь об этом. Если твой класс нужно иначе сравнивать, метод: `compare` - ужасная идея. Перегрузи `__eq__`, или `__hash__` и сравнивай с помощью `==`. Для этого надо знать [стандартные способы взаимодействия с объектами](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), [а тут посмотреть на возможности такой перегрузки](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html#a-more-interesting-example).
3. Многие простые задачи уже решены оптимальным образом. Посмотри: [Операции над функциями](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), [Встроенные функции](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)
4. Изучи [стандартную библиотеку](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). Там уже есть решения многих популярных задач. Есть все, чтобы мыслить не "кирпичами", а "крупными блоками".

Уверен, что в классах `Date` и `ContractData` нужны `protected` атрибуты? Может `dataclass`'ом тут все заменить?

Если да:

```
class TestCLS:
    __y = 2

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.__y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, val):
        self.__y = val
        return self.__y
```

Если нет:

```
class TestCLS:
    y: int

tc = TestCLS()
tc.y = 2
tc.y
```

Вместо `def printDate(self):`

```
class TestCLS:
    y = 3

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.y)

print(TestCLS())
```

На тему: `def initializateList(): global List`

1. `List` - это объект модуля `typing`. Коллеги тебя явно не правильно поймут.
2. Не используй глобальные переменные.
3. В общем случае не надо так работать с файлами.

Должно быть так:

```
    def initializateList():
        try:
            with open(file_way, 'rb') as f:
                contacts_list = pickle.load(f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            contacts_list = []
        return contacts_list
```

В функции `def showAllContacts():`

Вместо:

```
for i in range(len(List)):
    print("{} - {}".format(i + 1, List[i].getName()))
```

Надо:

```
for n, i in enumerate(List):
    print(n, '-', i.getName())
```

Поменяй: `del List[ch - 1]` -> `List.pop(ch-1)`

И последнее:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Load Data
    initializateList()

    #MainLoop
    while True:
    ...
```

`pickle` - это лучше использовать для сброса дампов и отладок. Для быстрой загрузки сложных объектов на этапе разработки.

Хранить рабочую информацию программы принято в: `ini`, `yaml`, `csv`, `*sql`, `hdf5` и прочих форматах.

И по аналогии правь остальное.

Не используй глобальные переменные. Функция должна получать то, что ей нужно и возвращать то, что нужно вызывающей функции.

Когда это все поправишь (про `pylint` не забудь), тогда можно будет что-либо про архитектуру говорить.

Comment: Что же касается приватных полей, то делал их таковым чисто по привычке соблюдать инкапсуляцию везде, где это возможно, но, как я понял, здесь есть своя специфика.

Comment: А на счёт того, что больно было код читать - ничего страшного, я и сам ощущал, а сейчас уж тем более, что сделал какого то монстра, буду исправляться

Comment: Не надо "так" соблюдать инкапсуляцию. Код усложнился, а пользы - никакой. Фактически ты меняешь значение переменных, просто делаешь это длинным и медленным способом. В python есть своя "философия" https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python#%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F и это не пустые слова.